# Keep Smart Object's percent resize in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, resize, adobe-creative-suite

I've been used to resize `Smart Objects` in `Photoshop CS2` without loose information on the original size of the object.

In CS2 If I resize the object from `100%` to `98%` in `width + height resize fields` and I want to adjust it back to `100%` it's simple because the fields keeps the resized percent.

Is it possible to set this option back again? Now in CS5 the width and height loose this information and go to `100%`, why this has been removed? does exists some way to keep this option back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this might be a known issue, and a bug has been logged. Update Photoshop and see if it gets fixed. Or try the solution recommended on the last post of this thread:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3340696

Answer (score 2):

What version of CS5 are you using?  I am running 12.0.4 x64 and it still gives me the option to scale it back to the original.  Maybe it's a bug in an earlier build.

Comment: I've been not very clear in my question, sorry, I'm using `CS5.0` I can scale back the smart object, but when I want to scale it again it starts from `100%` instead of `98%` as I set it before, in the older versions, photoshop kept the resize, now it seems this has been removed, but why? It was useful, I'm sure it isn't a bug because I've noticed the same problem in `CS4` too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the issue here.

Are you fully updated to either Photoshop 15.0.4 or 15.1? "CS5.0" could mean you have either 15.0.0, 15.0.1, 15.0.2 or 15.0.4. It may be a bug in early 15 releases as Julian points out.

Comment: that's what i was thinking as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a file that has a pre-scaled smart object in it. I figured out that if you select the smart object and keystroke "cmd + T" (Mac) or "crt + T" (windows), it will give you the pre scale size in the top bar. From there you can enter any size you wish and even go back to 100% with out losing any resolution quality. Hope this helps.